# AngularJS. Templates are not included in ui-views, when transitioning between child states of different abstract parents

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Templates are not included in ui-views, when transitioning between child states of different abstract parents.

[Here is the plunker](https://run.plnkr.co/rgrXc2us69ZstToH/#!/login) and [link to the editor](https://plnkr.co/edit/SflwggYknH4Fx86aCR2F?p=preview). Navigate form login (auth.login) state to dashboard (app.dashboard) state, header and footer templates are not included in ui-views.

Example of $stateProvider:

```
  .state('auth', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'app-outer': {
        templateUrl: 'auth.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('auth.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'app-inner': {
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'header.html'
      },
      'app-outer': {
        templateUrl: 'app.html'
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'footer.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
      'app-inner': {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

I've tried passing {reload: true} in the ui-sref-opts and used $state.go() method with {reload: true}.

As a temporary solution I've added header@app, footer@app etc. to the app.dashboard state. But it would be nice to not repeat this everywhere.

```
  'header@app': {
    templateUrl: 'header.html'
  },
  'app-inner': {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
  },
  'footer@app': {
    templateUrl: 'header.html'
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template `index.html` has `app-outer` view in it. `app.html` has `header`, `app-inner`, and `footer` in it. However, you have `header` and `footer` as views of app state, which corresponds to `index.html`. It looks like it attempts to populate those templates when the parent state first becomes active, before the child state (with `app.html`) is loaded, so it doesn't find the ui-views for the header and footer states.

In other words, it looks like a `ui-view` element corresponding to a view must exist at the time the state that defines that view becomes active.

See this [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1vHW8QTqvBxDxopyEH1f?p=preview), which insert another level of wrapping state.

Comment: Thanks, it's much better than a temporary solution that I've used, helps to keep it DRY.